# Binding a certificate to an azure function app

Tags: azure, letsencrypt

## Background

I’m attempting to teach myself some of the basic ins-and-outs of Azure. I’ve got a couple of domains that I’m now hosting the DNS for on Azure. From there, I’ve created a subdomain for one of said domains ( fn-app-01.[mydomain] ) that I want to associate with a function app. I also want to bind an SSL cert to this function app using a letsencrypt certificate.

I’m using https://github.com/shibayan/keyvault-acmebot to handle generating the letsencrypt certificate and I’ve got that all working ( assuming I do anyways ), as I’m able to generate the certificate for fn-app-01.[mydomain] and can see it in the key vault:

[image: key vault certificate]

The problem arises when I try to bind the certificate to the function app.

## Problem

When I attempt to import the certificate from the key vault, I get the following import error:

[image: Import Error]

I'm using RBAC and have assigned the following roles to my function
app within the key vault.

Current Roles for the function app:

[image: Current Roles for the function app]

So I'm a bit lost on how to proceed from here and how to solve the problem of binding the certificate to the function app. Am I missing something obvious here? Are these not the correct roles that my function app needs to be able to import a certificate from the key vault?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Guess: The function app needs the correct **access policies** for the keyvault, not RBAC roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it a bit more, dirkt was correct in their comment.

My solution was to basically use vault access policies instead of RBAC:

1. Within your key vault, go to Settings -> Access policies
2. Change the *Permission model* setting to use `Vault access policy`
3. Add a new access policy

   - Add certificate permissions of `Get` and `List`
   - Reference the function app you want to import the certificate for as the principal

After making the above changes, I was able to add/bind my SSL cert to the custom domain associated with my function app.

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled on why my initial RBACs didn't work. The roles I initially assigned to my function app seem to map to the same policies the above solution uses ( at least that's how I'm interrupting https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-migration ). Not sure what I'm missing there.